# Xml SelectSingleNode() returns null

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I searched this forum for similar questions but sadly all answers didn't help in my case neither the MSDN documentation.

I have created a TETML XML file that is an extract of a PDF file.
As the title suggests, I want to select a Node.
In the end, I want to directly go to the "Pages" node for later browsing.
None of my attempts were successful.
Even if I try to simply move to the Root element, I have no success:

[See Debugging in Visual Studio showing code and result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlsH6.png)

The code follows:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(FileRelatedOperations.ReadAllTextOfFile(filename, true, null));
XmlNamespaceManager nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsMgr.AddNamespace("t", "http://www.pdflib.com/XML/TET5/TET-5.0.xsd");

// No success with any of them:
doc.SelectSingleNode("TET");
doc.SelectSingleNode("/TET");
doc.SelectSingleNode("//TET");
doc.SelectSingleNode("t:TET", nsMgr);
doc.SelectSingleNode("/t:TET", nsMgr);
doc.SelectSingleNode("//t:TET", nsMgr);
doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("t:TET", nsMgr);
doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/t:TET", nsMgr);
doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//t:TET", nsMgr);
```

What could be the reason?
I tried it with/without a NamespaceManager.

Here is an abbreviated XML of the original one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created by the PDFlib Text and Image Extraction Toolkit TET (www.pdflib.com) -->
<TET xmlns="http://www.pdflib.com/XML/TET5/TET-5.0"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.pdflib.com/XML/TET5/TET-5.0
 http://www.pdflib.com/XML/TET5/TET-5.0.xsd"
 version="5.1">
    <Creation platform="Win32" tetVersion="5.1" date="2020-06-15T10:54:14+02:00" />
    <Document filename="C:\Temp\AnyPdfFile.pdf" pageCount="8" filesize="379366" linearized="false" pdfVersion="1.4" destination="D0">
        <DocInfo>
            <Author>Doxis4</Author>
            <CreationDate>2020-02-03T10:45:02+01:00</CreationDate>
            <Creator>Doxis4 Java API 7.4.2-r202829 (PDFDevice, ITextInterface)</Creator>
            <ModDate>2020-02-03T10:45:02+01:00</ModDate>
            <Producer>iText 2.1.7 by 1T3XT</Producer>
            <Title>Doxis4 Dokument</Title>
        </DocInfo>
        <Options>tetml={filename={C:\Temp\AnyPdfFile.pdf.xml}}</Options>
        <Action type="GoTo" trigger="open"/>
        <Pages>
            <Page number="1" width="595.00" height="842.00">
                <Options>layouthint={header=true} contentanalysis={bidilevel=ltr punctuationbreaks=false} docstyle=papers structureanalysis={list=true} layoutanalysis={layoutdetect=2 layoutrowhint={full separation=preservecolumns}} layouteffort=high granularity=word</Options>
                <Content granularity="word" dehyphenation="false" dropcap="false" font="false" geometry="false" shadow="false" sub="false" sup="false">
                    <Para>
                        <A id="A0" type="start"/>
                        <Box llx="40.00" lly="768.10" urx="315.40" ury="777.10">
                            <Word>
                                <Text>SomeTextHere</Text>
                                <Box llx="40.00" lly="768.10" urx="115.60" ury="777.10"/>
                            </Word>
                        </Box>
                    </Para>
                </Content>
            </Page>
        </Pages>
    </Document>
</TET>
```

Thank you in advance :-)!

Comment: Found schema at following locartion : http://www.pdflib.com/XML/TET5/TET-5.0.xsd
I used xsd.exe to generate c# classes,but your xml does not work with schema.  Is there a newer schema 5.1?  Is your xml valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What have you tried is good, but the default **NameSpace** that correspondent to **xmlns** is *http://www.pdflib.com/XML/TET5/TET-5.0* not *http://www.pdflib.com/XML/TET5/TET-5.0.xsd*, change the code to :

1 - Declaration and `XmlNamespaceManager` :

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(FileRelatedOperations.ReadAllTextOfFile(filename, true, null));

XmlNamespaceManager nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsMgr.AddNamespace("t", "http://www.pdflib.com/XML/TET5/TET-5.0");

nsMgr.AddNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
nsMgr.AddNamespace("schemaLocation", "http://www.pdflib.com/XML/TET5/TET-5.0 http://www.pdflib.com/XML/TET5/TET-5.0.xsd");
```

Note that, you don't need to `xsi` and `schemaLocation` namespaces declaration, if you want just to select `TET`.

2 - `SelectSingleNode` with `/t:TET` and **t** is *http://www.pdflib.com/XML/TET5/TET-5.0* :

```
XmlNode tetNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/t:TET", nsMgr);
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Hi Sajid, thank you so much for your second pair of eyes! Now even doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("t:Document/t:Pages", nsMgr) works fine :-)! I just needed to remove the 4 chars ".xsd" from my code and all went fine. Thank you!! Have a nice week! Cordt